# Can't access encrypted drive

Tags: encryption

I just bought a new SSD. I installed the new SSD in my laptop and installed Ubuntu Desktop 21.10. The old SSD is encrypted and has 20.04 LTS. I put the old SSD into an external enclosure and tried to access the files on it. The old SSD is recognized and a dialogue box opens up and asks for the password, which I put in, but I still can't access the files. "Files" shows a 1.6 GB drive, but if I look in "other locations" I see a 992 GB volume which is the old SSD and it has the files I want to access. I follow the path to the files I want Home>Darren and there is a file that is named "Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop" it's type is "Link (broken) (inode/symlink)". Any idea why putting in the password doesn't allow access to the files, and how I can get access to them? Will I just have to reinstall the old SSD in my laptop to get to the files?